# My CSS is transitioning only in one direction

Tags: javascript, css

Why is my CSS transitioning only in one direction?

I'm using the code below, and it works for the most part. Clicking btn1/2/3 animates the margin & visibility so that the old block fades out and moves up, but the new block just appears immediately and moves up following the old one - there is no transition in visibility on showing the block.

The page is arranged with sections appearing one under the other, in the order "menu-options", "overview", "capabilities", "approach".

EDIT: Note that the change in "display" is immediate for the new element to make it take up space on the page immediately, but it's visibility and location (via margin) should still transition. The display is delayed when setting to none so that it disappears only after it becomes invisible.

Created a junky sample implementation here: https://codepen.io/Sam-Vincent/pen/KKGbxXY

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  var btnback = document.getElementsByClassName("button-back");
  var btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName("button-overview");
  var btn2 = document.getElementsByClassName("button-capabilities");
  var btn3 = document.getElementsByClassName("button-approach");

  var menu = document.getElementById("menu-options");
  var section1 = document.getElementById("overview");
  var section2 = document.getElementById("capabilities");
  var section3 = document.getElementById("approach");

  var shown = menu;

  // Shows whichever element
  function show(element){
  element.style.display = "flex";
  element.style.visibility = "visible";
  element.style.opacity = 1;
  element.style.marginTop = "1px";
  }

  // Hides whichever Element if it"s shown
  function hide(element){
    element.style.marginTop = "calc(calc(100vh - 120px) * -1)";
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    element.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.style.display = "none";
    }, 1200);
  }

  // The action taken on clicking Back button
  function clickBack(){
    show(menu);
    hide(shown);
    shown = menu;
  }

  // The action taken on clicking Brief Overview button
  function clickOverview(){
    hide(shown);
    show(section1);
    shown = section1;
  }

  // The action taken on clicking Capabilities button
  function clickCapabilities(){
    hide(shown);
    show(section2);
    shown = section2;
  }

  // The action taken on clicking Approach button
  function clickApproach(){
    hide(shown);
    show(section3);
    shown = section3;
  }

  //Add event listener to back buttons
  function listenBack(button){
    button.addEventListener("click", clickBack);
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < btnback.length; ++index) {
    listenBack(btnback[index]);
  }

  //Add event listener to Overview buttons
  function listenOverview(button){
    button.addEventListener("click", clickOverview);
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < btn1.length; ++index) {
    listenOverview(btn1[index])
  }

  //Add event listener to Capabilities buttons
  function listenCapabilities(button){
    button.addEventListener("click", clickCapabilities);
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < btn2.length; ++index) {
    listenCapabilities(btn2[index])
  }

  //Add event listener to Approach buttons
  function listenApproach(button){
    button.addEventListener("click", clickApproach);
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < btn3.length; ++index) {
    listenApproach(btn3[index])
  }

  function fastHide(element){
    element.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
    hide(element);
    element.style.transition = "all 1.2s ease";
  }
  fastHide(section1);
  fastHide(section2);
  fastHide(section3);
});
</script>
<style>
#menu-options, #overview, #capabilities, #approach {
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It's hard to guess what's happening without playing around with a demo

Comment: Edited, added codepen example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in css,
display: 'none' -> display: 'block' is not accepting any transition.
And appears immediately.
You should use as
opacity: 0 -> opacity: 1
It will accept transition.

Comment: why this is not working?